# AppleScript : Safari page fully loaded / Dialog in full screen windows

Tags: safari, dialog, applescript, wait

I try with so much snipped but cannot get my script to wait for safari (9.0.1) to full loaded the web page I want.

Any idea which works with OSX 10.11 / Safari 9.0.1 ?

Also, at the moment I have a really simple dialogue for timing "is safari fully loaded?"

However I have my Safari open in a full screen, and so the dialog will popup on the main desktop screen instead.

Can I not focus the dialog to wherever safari is?

```
set infotosearch to the clipboard

if infotosearch is equal to missing value then
    --do nothing
else
    tell application "Safari"

        tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 1
        -- Last Name
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('11111')[0].value=" & quoted form of infotosearch & "" in document 1
        -- search
        delay 0.1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('111112')[0].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end if

-- FOCUS ON SAFARI 

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
    end tell

end tell
-- END FOCUS 

-- Dialog as cannot wait for safari page fully loaded

display dialog "Is MZ Fully loaded?" buttons {"Yes", "NO"} default button 2
if the button returned of the result is "" then
    -- nothing
else
    -- nothing
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way to check if Safari has finished to load full page, is to check in the source code of the page contains the end balise "".

This script is  doing that:

```
set myUrl to "http://www.google.com"
tell application "Safari"
make new document with properties {URL:myUrl}
delay 1
tell document 1
    repeat until ("</html>" is in its source)
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

I hope it helps.

I also remember have seen a java instruction to get page loaded status. it does the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help, is not working for me though, I just put a 10sec delay for now anyway

Comment: Actually my delay solutions kill me already! Basically the script it filling a search query on the tab already open in safari, click search and the I need to wait that the search is completed, tried this script without the url variable and changed the html keyword by something else in the website but that just stopping the script without error message for some reason

Comment: if the script stops, it is because it founds the new keyword in the source of the page. Are you sure your keyword is not already somewhere in the source of the page before end of the search ?

Comment: That's brilliant, many thanks was looking for that from month ! (here is the integration for my script) try
 
 tell application "Safari"
  
  tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 1
  tell document 1
   repeat until ("TEXT HERE" is in its source)
    delay 0.5
   end repeat
  end tell
 end tell
 
on error
 
 
end try